# How to include ts-topojson into Angular2 app?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, topojson

How would I import [ts-topojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-topojson) into an Angular2 project so I get Typescript typings? I installed the module using npm and tried to include with a simple import statement but the linter said it couldn't find 'topojson'.

```
import { Topojson } from 'topojson';
```

This is my first Angular2 project so I'm very new at this so I could possibly be missing a crucial step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the package [`@types/topojson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/topojson) with `npm install @types/topojson --save-dev`.

Now you can use `topojson` the following way within a component:

```
import {topology, feature, ...} from 'topojson';
```

Or with:

```
import * as t from '@types/topojson';
```

Comment: For me it says `Module '"../../node_modules/@types/topojson"' has no exported member 'feature'.`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Make sure the script is loaded into your `scripts` in `.angular-cli.json`.
2. At the top of a file you want to use the library, add `declare let Topojson: any;`.

Now you can use `Topojson` without the TS compiler yelling at you, because it will be implied that it's loaded as a script and made available to you during runtime.